# Apache layer issue converting https to http

Tags: java, apache, http, https

I have Apache 2.2 load balancer installed and Weblogic 12c server installed.

I have observed that a https URL was attempting to open a http URL in my application which was unsuccessful, as expected. I searched why this could have caused the problem and noticed something here -

http://geekexplains.blogspot.in/2008/06/https-becoming-http-in-case-of.html

When I tried to look for a fix, I found the following links -

[Fix in Apache layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22476484/1649068)

and

[Fix in Java layer](http://www.hoitikwong.com/2013/03/the-mystery-case-of-https-becoming-http.html)

I am not keen on making fix in Java layer (or I would rather keep that as my last option), So I tried the fix suggested in the Apache layer, but didn't work (mod_jk.so was not available in my httpd.conf file though)

Any suggestions that can be provided will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

At the Apache layer you could do a simple:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.hostname.tld
    Redirect permanent / https://www.hostname.tld/
</VirtualHost>
```

To redirect any request for http to https.  This assumes that the client software can handle redirects.  Browsers are great at it.  Homegrown HTTP clients may or may not be.

Comment: Thank you @stdunbar. But I am still unable to achieve the loading of https url here. This is what I'm trying to do in my `httpd.conf` file - `Redirect permanent / https://my.server.name/` - My application didn't load.Everytime I Inspect Element in the browser, I get this message constantly - `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my.server.name/MyHome.do?page2=home' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://my.server.name/service/overwrite=true&__locale=en_US&__timezone=US/Central&NlsLang=English'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: I also tried `Redirect permanent /* https://my.server.name/` - My app loaded, but was still trying to load a http URL.

Comment: I believe this requires SSL configuration to be made in `httpd.conf` file.

`<VirtualHost *:443>
# .. SSL Configuration..
</VirtualHost>`