# How to stop sendRedirect and encodeRedirectURL from converting URL from https to http

Tags: java, http, servlets, https

I have 3 different server environments, out of them in one of the server environments the following line in the code is mysteriously converting "HTTPS" Download URL to "HTTP" on redirection

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(publicationURL));
```

Here is the complete function which use this line

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"exampleUrlPath","exampleUrlPath"})

    public ModelAndView downloadDocument(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            @PathVariable String reportId) throws IOException {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = null;
        final String publicationID = request.getParameter("publicationId");
        String publicationURL = retrieveFacade.getPublicationURL(publicationID);
        publicationURL = publicationURL.replaceAll("\"", "");
        if (null != publicationURL) {

           // publication URL is HTTPS here as per the logs... 

           response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(publicationURL));
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

the strange thing is that it is only happening in one of the environments and not on the other two servers. All three servers are using HTTPS.

Because of this conversion, my download is not happening due to the "mixed content" issue.

What type of configuration I should check to overcome this issue. (conf file, htaccess file etc)

Server info: Apache Wildfly

Host: AWS

found these questions little connected with my issue.

[How to Reproduce sendRedirect issue - HTTPS change to HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891210/how-to-reproduce-sendredirect-issue-https-change-to-http)

[How to redirect to https on tomcat behind ELB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542488/how-to-redirect-to-https-on-tomcat-behind-elb)

Comment: You probably have frontend server (http, proxy, etc) which does SSL termination and forwards your request to Wildfly using plain http. Double check that configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Gas, I am rechecking the configuration in somewhere middle.